# AngularJS - multiple forms - one ng-model?

Tags: forms, angularjs

Let's say I have twitter-like website populated with messages. There is a feature that you can add comments to messages.

So, I iterate over each message and display a comment form:

```
<div class="" ng-repeat="msg in messages">
    <span>message: {{msg.message}}</span>
    <span>date {{msg.date}}</span>
    <form ng-submit="">
        <input type="text" ng-model="commentForm.comment">
        <button type="submit" value="send">
    </form>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I type comment under one message it's being displayed over all inputs, that's not the behavior I want.

- Disabling with disabled="true" other input fields doesn't help.

Here is the code: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/u0kxU9ApKMDiGt06Jr1A?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the code you provided, all the text inputs bind to the same ng-model variable.  So, when one of those values change they'll be updated.  You may be better off storing the comment as part of the original object.

In the controller:

```
$scope.messages = [
    {'message': 'here goes some message',
        'date': '1-1-2014',
        'comment':''
    },
    {'message': 'here goes another message',
        'date': '2-2-2014',
        'comment':''
    }
];
```

And in the html:

```
<div class="" ng-repeat="msg in messages">
        <input type="text" ng-model="msg.comment">
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/DeUyHXsXJLUESXTAnwGY?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You are using the object commentForm declared in the script.js, which is unique.

```
<span>Comments:</span>
<form ng-submit="">
    <input type="text" ng-model="msg.commentForm">
    <button type="submit">send</button
</form>
<br>
```

Will create a field commentForm for you in each "msg" object.